# Ajax request not reaching the servlet

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

i am sending an ajax post request from a `javascript` file but it is not reaching the servlet

i got error from IE console as `error 404` not found

web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Edit</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Edit</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

JavaScript AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: 'Edit?action=edit',
    data: {
        env: env,
        region: region,
        url: url,
        rnode: rnode,
        user: user,
        password: password,
        envid: envid,
        attuid: attuid
    },
    success: function() {
        alert("row has has been modified");
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        if (xhr.responseText == "Internal server error")
            alert("row cannot be changed , internal server error");
    }
});
```

servlet package and code:

```
 `/EnvInfo/src/com/amdocs/infraportal/servlets/Edit.java`

 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req , HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,IOException
{
    res.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
    String n=req.getParameter("action");
    System.out.println("welcome"+n);
    if(n.equalsIgnoreCase("edit"))
    {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "request is going to servlet");
    }
 }
```

request is not going to servlet at all , tried all combinations of path in `URL` but still not working

ps - i am accessing this from a `onclick` event

Comment: What does your JavaScript look like to make the request?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically this should work (I don't have access to a tomcat server right now)

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app> <!-- I didn't include all the xml web-app stuff. make sure you do -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Edit</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.amdocs.infraportal.servlets.Edit</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Edit</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Edit</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Java:

```
public class Edit extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Edit', //I don't think you should use a query string, you are posting so just add action to your data object
    data: yourData,
    type: 'post'
}).done(function (data){ //this style of ajax is up to preference
    //do something
}).fail(function (err){
    //handle error
});
```